# Go: pointer as map key type

Tags: pointers, dictionary, go, set

I'm looking for a proper way to implement a set of pointers to `struct`. The obvious method is the of use built-in `map`:

```
map[*SomeStructure]struct{}
```

But does Go memory model guarantees that it's safe to use pointers as `map` key type? 
Isn't it possible for runtime to optimize pointer addresses out (may be) due to address space defragmentation?

Comment: What do you mean by pointers to struct{}. Areyou trying to implement Set

Comment: You can use a pointer as a map key. I don't know what it would mean to "optimize pointer addresses out".

Comment: @JimB I suspect that go runtime may change pointer address values for some kind of optimization. Is it absolutely impossible?

Comment: @VitalyIsaev: Why do you suspect that? Pointer values are a fundamental part of the language, and if there ever is an optimization that requires moving pointers (which isn't expected to happen), it will need to be done transparently to the user. Pointers are used as map keys throughout the std library, just search for `map[*`.